# Autologin working sporadically?

Tags: support, status-norepro, login, auto-login

I'm a member of several SE sites and not a member of others. During the course of the day, I find myself having to log in several times, while other times it automatically logs me in. When am I logged in and when am I not?

https://stackoverflow.com/network-login-help tells me I'm fine. In fact, when I went there, it logged me in. However, the first stop this morning was to log in at stackexchange.com and then click through to a few questions I'd asked on Personal Finance and Money, at which point I was logged out...? This despite getting there from the "Inbox" on the top-left dropdown, which only appears when I'm logged in. I had to login with my Google account again.

using IE8 with InPrivate Browsing, could that be interfering?

ETA: Today's path:

1. www.stackexchange.com. Logged in via Google.
2. Via inbox, went to money.stackexchange.com. Had to log in again via Google.
3. Went to stackoverflow.com to use the network login tool. Was auto-logged in.
4. Browsed programmers.stackexchange.com, where I have no login. Was not logged in (correctly).
5. Went to english.stackexchange.com, where I have a login. Had to log in again via Google.

Not once did I see the behavior whereby I click "login" and it auto-logs me in. I haven't visited any sites before this path today, and it wipes my history and cookies when I close IE so it's not holding over from yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InPrivate Browser is probably what's causing this.

Our global login system requires cross domain communication and localStorage to function properly.  Presumably InPrivate Browsing is interfering at least with localStorage, it definitely does when restarting the browser.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/09/16/bugs-in-ie8-support-for-html5-postmessage-sessionstorage-and-localstorage.aspx seems to indicate that it's (meant to be) operational but isolated from other sessions, unless I misread?

It mentions a bug across tabs, but I often use the same tab.