# Numerous logins

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Network wide login](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145427/network-wide-login)

Why do we need to log into each site individually for s.e. and then also have an open id to log in as well? I answered a question and got an email asking to verify my account and also register with open id, isnt one log in enough?