# I did not get "welcome back" message

Tags: support, stack-exchange, login

I recently logged in on StackOverflow and then visited a stackexchange site where I also have an account. I used Google Chrome.
I did not receive a "Welcome back, user, you have been logged in" message. However, on a different computer, I got this message with any browser if there are no cookies.

The message seems to indicate that the site logs me in automatically. It remains unclear why this does not always happen.
Can the missing message/login have to do something with different hardware or software configurations?

Comment: That's never how it worked; you log in for each site, and that login times out after some (long) time.

Comment: Related, and in need of an authoritative answer: [When does a login happen automatically?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140567/when-does-a-login-happen-automatically)

Comment: I'm sorry dude. Welcome back!

Comment: As an aside: I think my comments on [When does a login happen automatically?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140567/when-does-a-login-happen-automatically) explains what you've been seeing? Note that every now and then all existing sessions are invalidated on the server (like, I assume, when something was rebooted), requiring a new login.

Comment: Hi Arjan, thanks for the link, but it doesn´t really make it clear.