# In IE9 InPrivate mode, logging in to one site does not log me in on others

Tags: support, login

Whenever I switch to a new site (domain), I am not recognized, and I have to click "Log in" and then the Stack Exchange icon (which actually works *without* asking for my password) to get to my account and Inbox.

I'm using IE9's InPrivate mode, but since I'm in only one session, and the SE icon works without additional input, I expected to have direct access without the need to go through the additional page. Am I missing something in the settings somewhere?

Comment: Do you meet all requirements in [what else do I need?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need/71208#71208)

Comment: Related: [When does a login happen automatically?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140567/when-does-a-login-happen-automatically)

Comment: On Scripting: "Options - Security - Scripting - Active Scripting" is enabled, but i don't know if there are other places i should check...

On Cookies: Privacy is set to medium, with no override of automatic cookie handling. Should i add these sites to a white-list?

On "Site Accessibility" - i'm not sure WHAT to check for here... :-s

Comment: Sounds like that might be a "feature" of InPrivate mode since effectively the automatic login is indistinguishable from a cross-domain tracking network.

Comment: But in that case wouldn't the login page require the credentials again? Basically, i was thinking that the page could already check for the StackExchange data, if it exists, and not require me to actively choose it...

Comment: What results do you get at http://stackoverflow.com/network-login-help ?

Comment: "Success! All necessary browser features are enabled and functioning for network-wide automatic login."

Comment: Does this happen multiple times for the same session, or once per session?

Comment: It's once per session, since i'm not in the habit of logging out. I either completely shut down all browser instances or keep them running with my account logged in.

Answer (score 1):

First check that everything's enabled that needs to be, by visiting https://stackoverflow.com/network-login-help

Next check that you've got all the relevant sites allowed to set cookies:

```
*.stackauth.com          # needed: to support autologin 
openid.stackexchange.com # needed: this sends you a third party cookie
*.stackoverflow.com      # my favourite
*.stackexchange.com      # for those other interesting founts of knowledge
```

`stackauth.com` is also (AFAIK) a third party cookie - you don't ordinarily visit stackauth.com, but you get a cookie for it remotely when you're logged in on a Stack Exchange site.

To allow this, you either have to enable third party cookies globally (which I find distasteful and intrusive) or give `stackauth.com` and `openid.stackexchange.com` special permission, perhaps by adding them to your trusted sites list.

---

### Cookie lifetime

Since this happens once per session, it's almost certainly because InPrivite mode is designed to clear your history on exit, and probably clears all the cookies. Try adding the sites above to your trusted sites list to see if you get more persistence.

Comment: Apparently, stackauth.com cannot (or does not want to) set cookies, but the other sites can (and have). Now i'm curious what was preventing the Auth site from behaving like the others...

Comment: @C.B. maybe third partyness - see updated answer.

Comment: I'll try to look into the permissions, but FWIW i already have a openid.stackexchange.com cookie, without any special action on my part.

Comment: @C.B. Have you tried adding to trusted sites?

Comment: OK, added *.stackauth.com to Trusted Sites, and at first i thought it didn't help, but then i noticed that the auto-login ("Welcome back, you've been logged in. Click here to refresh the page.") didn't happen right away, and i had to wait a few seconds for it. I usually saw the "sign up / log in" links and used them ASAP, before the message managed to pop out. Although meta.SO still doesn't follow suit...

Comment: Oh, one more thing: apparently, adding to Trusted Sites might have had some kind of side effect, since after removing stackauth from there i now still get the auto-login working (except on meta).

Comment: @C.B. Probably because you still have the cookie from stackauth.com until you restart. Adding meta.stackoverflow.com separately will probably allow you to autologin here too.

Comment: Maybe, but i don't think so, since it's a new session and i am asked for credentials again so i would expect cookies to be "gone"... As for adding meta.SO to Trusted Sites, it didn't work.