# Does not always log in automatically when going from one SE site to another

Tags: support, bug, login

About half the time when I am logged into one SE site, and then go to another one, it automatically logs me in like it is supposed to.  Half the time, it does not.

Given that I can perform the identical action two times in a row, and get two different behaviors, there appears to be something amiss, and not some sort of configuration issue.

Tested using Firefox (latest release).  Yes, I've cleared the cache, deleted all cookies, reinstalled the browser, rebooted the machine, made sure it's plugged in, tickled the mouse, et al.

**UPDATE #1**: Just a quick update, written a little more than six months after this original post.  Things started to get better for a while, with the SE logins working better.  Now things seem to be about back to square one.

**UPDATE #2**: Something has changed, and now the failure to auto-login happens ***every*** time I log into a site like [Software Recommendations SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), and then click on an unread inbox message for [Superuser](http://superuser.com).  When I click on those links, I am ***never*** automatically logged into Superuser.

Comment: Aye, this bugs me too. See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140567/when-does-a-login-happen-automatically?rq=1 The answer is wrong because it does not happen how the answer states it "does".

Comment: @James +1 What you wrote is my experience as well.  From what I can tell, it doesn't work as claimed.

Comment: Do you have any browser extensions/plug-ins installed?  Does it happen on multiple browsers, or on multiple computers/devices, or from multiple different IP addresses?  Providing this kind of information can potentially help troubleshoot.

Comment: To answer your questions, in order: Yes, Yes, Yes, Yes.  Well, the answers are all yes, so the order did not matter. :-)

Comment: After nearly 6 years, this is still true.