# Automatically log me in to my related account I've navigated to from my profile

Tags: feature-request, login, auto-login

When logged in and viewing your account profile, navigating to a related account where you are not logged in, means that you get the public view of the account.

I always want to be automatically logged when coming from the profile view.

Comment: Could you explain a little more what you mean?

Comment: I have 26 stack exchange accounts, some of them I visit frequently, some extremely infrequently.  The ones that I visit infrequently, I am typically not logged into.  When I go to my profile for Stack Overflow and then use my account links to navigate to one that I am not currently logged into on this computer, say Travel, I believe I should be automatically logged into that account.

Comment: Why only using your profile? Why not when you visit any page on the site?

Comment: When the site is in the list of Hot Network Questions and I go there, and I don't get logged in, fine, I wanted to look at a question, doesn't matter if I'm logged in or not, I get to look at the question.  When I am on the profile page and I click on the link to my account on another site, I don't expect to see that "standard" view, I expect to see MY account with my details. Not the details I'd see for someone else.

Answer (score 1):

In fact that should already happen (according to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/140567/245360)). When you visit a site where you are a member, you are automatically logged in to that site if you are logged in to another site in the network.

It seems to me something might be wrong with your profile(s) if the behavior described in that post is not happening using your account.

(If this all is true, your feature request doesn't make sense, hence, I disagree it should be implemented. It should be implemented for all pages, not just your profile. This is how it is already)

Comment: There is a caveat or two in that post and the related blog: I think that specifically for navigating from the profile page, the "recently" and "not visited the site without being logged in" shouldn't apply.  I don't know about you, but I access the site from different devices and some of them I don't login very often...